# VBA Excel "Variables are required"

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Got a trouble in a VBA excel program.

```
Sub code(s)
...
code = t
End Sub
```

And then :

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
...
For i = 0 To size
    current_y = code(string_array(i))
...
End Sub
```

When i run the program, i got this error "Variables are required" (not sure, i'm working on a japanese version of excel). Sub CommandButton1_Click is highlighted and code is selected inside CommandButton1_Click. Can't figure out why, though it must be simple...

Comment: Side Note:  Strongly type that s (e.g. _s as Integer_).  Otherwise, it defaults to a most likely unneeded Variant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to return a result from a Sub. Try declaring it as a function instead, as this is able to return values to the caller:

```
Function code(s)
...
code = t
End Function
```

If it makes it any clearer, on my English version the error message is:

> Expected Function or variable

Comment: Yeah, total speed demon, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Does the code include Option Explicit?  Perhaps the error translates to "Variable declaration required"?  Try removing option explicit - if that fixes it remove that line, then go through checking all variables are declare (e.g. dim current_y as string).